# NullReferenceException with adapted Create in Umbraco 4.9

Tags: c#, umbraco, nullreferenceexception

I have adapted the Umbraco create context menu item in order to duplicate content. I have been working through it sorting small problems but I am now stuck. When trying to use the `dialogHandler_temp.Create()` method I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

All of the variables used are not null nor is the page. Does anyone have an idea how I could sort this?

```
    private void DoCreation()
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    var hel = helper.Request("nodeType");
    var nType = int.Parse(nodeType.SelectedValue);
    var nId = int.Parse(Request["nodeID"]);
    var rName = rename.Text;
    var cur = Current;


    if (cur != null) // dialogHandler_temp.Create() is a static method
        cur.ClientTools.ChangeContentFrameUrl(dialogHandler_temp.Create(hel, nType, nId, rName)).CloseModalWindow();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.presentation.create.dialogHandler_temp.Create(String NodeType, Int32 TypeId, Int32 NodeId, String Text) +278
   OptionalMultiLangPage.DoCreation() in c:\inetpub\wwwAmaris\optional_multiLang.aspx.cs:112
   OptionalMultiLangPage.SbmtClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwAmaris\optional_multiLang.aspx.cs:96
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3803
```

Comment: how about dialogHandler_temp? check dialogHandler_temp null or not and also provide full stack trace of the exception

Comment: `dialogHandler_temp` - where does this variable come from? Where and how is it defined and initialized?

Comment: @Andrei it is part of Umbraco and is utilized by Umbraco itself to create nodes. It can be found under `umbraco.presentation.create`

Comment: @Andrei I should have mentioned, it actually returns the url for the new node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted. It took me a while to realise that `helper.Request("nodeType")` wasn't to return the new node's type, rather the xml node value of what is being done. This must be assigned somewhere out-with the the Umbraco Content class so I missed it. It should be set to the value of `"content"`.

My code now looks like:

```
 private void DoCreation()
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        const string xmlNodeVal = "content";
        var nType = int.Parse(nodeType.SelectedValue);
        var nId = int.Parse(Request["nodeID"]);
        var rName = rename.Text;
        var returnUrl = dialogHandler_temp.Create(xmlNodeVal, nType, nId, rName);
        var cur = Current;

        if (cur != null)
            cur.ClientTools.ChangeContentFrameUrl(returnUrl).CloseModalWindow();
    }
```